# how to update d3 chart when receiving new DATA

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, charts

How to update the d3 chart with new data :
am implemting on ngOnchanges three functions :

```
        this.removeSvg(this.data);
        this.createSvg();
        this.drawBars(this.data);
```

where createSvg() :

```
private createSvg(): void {
    this.svg = d3.select("figure#histogram")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", '100%')
        .attr("height", '100%')
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + "," + this.margin + ")");
}
```

and removeSvg() :

```
       this.svg = d3.select("figure#histogram")
       .exit().remove()
       d3.select("#histogram").select("svg").remove();
```

and drawBars(data : any [] ) :

```
private drawBars(data: any[]): void {
    // Create the X-axis band scale
    const x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([this.axisMin, 340])
        .domain(data.map(d => d.xAxis))
        .padding(0);

    // Create the Y-axis band scale
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, this.axisMax])
        .range([this.height, 0])
        .nice();


    // Create and fill the bars
    this.svg.selectAll("bars")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))
        .attr("fill", "rgb(13, 185, 240)");
}
```

but it is not refreshing the chart , even if am sure that data is refreshing ( so for the first chart we continue having all other charts as if it is same data )
any help ? maybe remove or exit are false here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3, manipulating the DOM can be done with selections. In your `drawBars()` function you use the `enter` selection which describes what happens to new data.
To describe what happens to data that has changed, use the `update` selection; for data that leaves, use the `exit` selection. To follow the updated data, you need a key function on the `data()` call that uniquely identifies each element.

[See this tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/learn-d3-joins?collection=@d3/learn-d3) for a more in-depth overview.

In your `drawBars()` function:

```
private drawBars(data: any[]): void {
    // ...
    let t = svg.transition().duration(500);
    
    this.svg.selectAll("bars")
        .data(data, d => d)
        .join(
        enter => enter
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
            .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))
            .attr("fill", "rgb(13, 185, 240)"),
        update => update.call(update => update.transition(t)
            .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
            .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
            .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))),
        exit => exit.call(exit => exit.transition(t)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .remove()))
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen for replying , but didn't work ! it keeps appending previous chart bars on top of the new chart bars

Answer (score 1):

resolved !

for any one who faces this problem I advice him with this solution :
just keep everything as it is , but make sure to refresh the data on each change , then empty the svg of all its elements with :

```
his.svg.selectAll("*").remove()
```

, then draw the chart again with new data .

Answer (score 0):

```
this.svg.selectAll("bars")
        .data(data, d => d)
        .join(
            enter => enter
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
                .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
                .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))
                .attr("fill", "rgb(13, 185, 240)"),
            update => update.call(update => update
                .transition(t)
                .attr("x", d => x(d.xAxis))
                .attr("y", d => y(d.yAxis))
                .attr("height", (d) => this.height - y(d.yAxis))),
            exit => exit.call(exit => exit
                .transition(t)
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("height", 0)
                .remove()))
```

this didn't helped to make transition when updating data .